# Can a web service callout be made in code that has a "for update" lock applied?

Tags: webservices, callout, for-update

I believe a motivation for the platform not allowing DML before a web service callout is to avoid a long-lived transaction (as the callout is allowed to wait up to 10 seconds for its response).

I have a query that I want to use a ["for update" locking statement](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_locking_statements.htm) in to ensure some processing is only done once. But immediately following that query I want to make a web service callout. It occurs to me that this may also be disallowed by the platform (locking requiring a transaction?) or be potentially problematic but I haven't found any documentation on the subject.

Can a web service callout be made in code that has a "for update" lock applied?

Comment: Should be simple enough to mock up. Get account in a for update DML. Perform a callout immediately after to any random site. Did you give it a shot?

Comment: @Eric This came up in some refactoring so quite soon next week I'll find out. Taking the lazy approach by asking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have now run the code and it is working fine - so the answer is **yes**.

Comment: I was just going in to mock this up. Glad you got the answer. Although, not sure why SF will not allow DML before a callout. Just provide us a method to commit before a callout so the decision is deliberate on the part of the developer

Comment: Of course, keep in mind that holding any lock longer than necessary can affect other users in the system.